# How to know whether a copying process(scp) is complete using python?

Tags: python, shell, centos7, scp, sshpass

I have a python program for log analysis. 
The log is in another server which has a port number and password.

I cannot store my python code in that server. So I need to scp the file to the server where my program is stored.

I did this:

```
popen('''sshpass -p "password" scp -r \
    admin@192.158.11.109:/home/admin/DontDeleteMe/%s /home/admin/''' % fileName)
```

But if the file is big the program will run before completing the copying process.

Answer (score 1):

`popen()` does not wait for the process to complete. You can use `subprocess.call()`:

```
exitcode = subprocess.call('''sshpass -p "password" scp -r \
    admin@192.158.11.109:/home/admin/DontDeleteMe/%s /home/admin/''' % fileName,
    shell=True)
```

According to Python's [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

> The `subprocess` module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes. **This module intends to replace several older modules and functions:**
>
> ```
> os.system
> os.spawn*
> os.popen*
> popen2.*
> commands.*
> ```